# net::ERR_ABORTED 429 (Too Many Requests), Access... blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQcM.jpg

Any ideas what could be the problem here please?

My input file has 635 lines; but I'm also seeing that when I try with a much smaller file of 60 or even 30 lines I'm still getting the same problem.

I think my app has the user agent set correctly:

```
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'CSV for Discogs/0.1',
  }
```

Any pointers? TIA.

Comment: As the error complains about, have you checked your CORS settings? Are you sure they are correct or that you do not need them and have set the no-cors flag? Use a search engine for a tutorial if you do not know what CORS is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I'm reading about CORS right now. I thought these settings are on the server side though, are they not? Which I don't have control over, my app accesses https://api.discogs.com/ Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin , it says "If the server is under your control" which suggests to me these CORS settings are on the API server's side. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Both server and client have to set certain settings. So the api already has the correct headers. If I inspect the response from api.discogs.com, I see it has `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `A-C-Allow-Methods`, `A-C-Expose-Headers` and `A-C-Allow-Origin`. So maybe it's as simple as just setting `withCredentials` to `true` on the request made by the client. Although this should be standard, also make sure your server actually allows `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` http requests to be made. I remember I had to explicitly allow it in some libraries.

Comment: > setting withCredentials to true

How would I do that? Same as shown here, maybe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: No idea. I just add it manually on the `XMLHttpRequest` created by the ajax library I use, as described in the link you provided. How do you call the api?

Comment: From the browser, I suppose you would say:

    function getRelease(id) {
      return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'CSV for Discogs/0.1',
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(parseReleaseData)
      }

Comment: For `fetch()`, you can use the `credentials` property. So try something like: `fetch(https://api.discogs.com/releases/${id}, { headers: { 'User-Agent': 'CSV for Discogs/0.1', }, credentials: 'include', mode: 'cors' })` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters Maybe you need `referrerPolicy` as well. But I haven't worked with the init parameters of `fetch()` myself yet, so not sure which and which not to include.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the other part of the issue that isn't CORS related.

https://www.discogs.com/de/forum/thread/782204

You are over your allowed request limit, as described in the discogs docs:

https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-rate-limiting

Comment: Right, thanks. I was looking at that earlier too. I've no idea how to throttle my apps' requests though.

Comment: Store the timestamp of the request somewhere, like an array. Then check before making the request that the array does not have the maximum amount inside your allowed timeframe yet. Filtering out the requests that were made the previous timeframe, can either be done while checking ( no timer needed ) or every time a new timeframe starts. ( timer needed )